# s2s google calendar API, sharing calendar to service

Tags: ruby, calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have an app using s2s connection with google calendar api. I need to create an event in different users calendars. To make it possible the user should go to the calendar's settings and share their calendar to the service account.
But I would like to simplify this for the user - so that they don't need to go to their calendar settings. I don't have an interface for the user interaction - it's a bot.
How can I access the user's calendar in another way?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change the role set by the user to the calendar. According to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/sharing#sharing_calendars), the owners of a calendar can share the calendar by giving access to other users. The sharing settings of a given calendar are represented by the ACL collection (access control list) of that calendar. Each resource in the ACL collection grants a specified grantee a certain access role. So the user can make you the writer or owner of their calendar, so that you can access it.

Another way is by using [Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority),

> If you have a Google Apps domain—if you use Google Apps for Work, for
>   example—an administrator of the Google Apps domain can authorize an
>   application to access user data on behalf of users in the Google Apps
>   domain. For example, an application that uses the Google Calendar API
>   to add events to the calendars of all users in a Google Apps domain
>   would use a service account to access the Google Calendar API on
>   behalf of users. Authorizing a service account to access data on
>   behalf of users in a domain is sometimes referred to as "delegating
>   domain-wide authority" to a service account